# Wrong pgfplots linear regression computing

Tags: pgfplots, pgfplotstable

I'm try to plot the following data:

```
\pgfplotstableread[col sep=semicolon]{
record;value
2004;48
2009;34
2010;32
2016;22
2020;21
}\valuetotest
```

by

```
\pgfkeys{
/pgf/number format/.cd,
set decimal separator={,{\!}},
set thousands separator={}}
\begin{tikzpicture}[]
\begin{axis}[
grid=both, %none
major grid style={thick},
xtick distance={5},
ytick distance={10},
minor x tick num=4,
minor y tick num=4,
width=13.5cm, height=13cm,
axis x line=middle, 
axis y line=middle, 
samples=100,
ymin=-0.2, ymax=60.5,
xmin=2000, xmax=2025,
domain=2000:2025,
xlabel={Years},
ylabel={$\mu g/m^3$}
]
\addplot[only marks,mark=square*,blue] table[x=record,y=value] {\valuetotest};
    \addlegendentry{values}
\addplot[no marks,blue,dashed,] table[header=false,x=record,y={create col/linear regression={y=value}}] {\valuetotest};
    \addlegendentry{pgfplots computed lin regr}
\addplot[smooth,orange,domain=2000:2025]{\pgfplotstableregressiona*x+\pgfplotstableregressionb};
    \addlegendentry{a =\pgfmathprintnumber[]{\pgfplotstableregressiona}; b=\pgfmathprintnumber[]{\pgfplotstableregressionb}}
\addplot[smooth,blue,domain=2000:2025]{-1.674744898*x+3400.651786};
    \addlegendentry{manual lin regr}
\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
```

but as shown in the picture pgfplots seems to compute the wrong value of the linear regression (I computed the "manual ones" by excel).

[image]

THX in advance

Comment: Unrelated: don't use `\table` as a macroname when reading in a table of data, it will break the `table` environment, because `\begin{table}` calls `\table`. But indeed, `pgfplots` fails here. You could post a bug report at https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgfplots I suppose. TeX isn't the most powerful calculator around, I'm guessing this is a numerical issue. If you for example subtract 2000 from the x-values you get the correct answer.

Comment: @Torbjørn T. thx. I noticed too that the computation would be correct using smaller x-values. I suppose the best way here is to implement either a manual or external computation. Aside I changed `\table` into to `\valuetotest`.